# Programming an Android Button to update EditText views

Tags: android, button, random, numbers, android-edittext

Ok guys, I have a button in android that i'm trying to use to update 8 EditText Views with different random numbers.  Everything works up until I click the button.  It appears I am missing a resource according to the debugger, but I'm not sure what.  I've tried several different ways of implementing the button.  Here is what I have after looking at several posts.

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MyCharNewChar extends MyCharActivity {


private OnClickListener randomButtonListener = new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Button creates a set of random numbers and updates the values
        //of the EditText views.

        Random rand = new Random();
        int STR = 1 + rand.nextInt(12);
        int AGI = 1 + rand.nextInt(12);
        int DEX = 1 + rand.nextInt(12);
        int WIS = 1 + rand.nextInt(12);
        int INT = 1 + rand.nextInt(12);
        int CON = 1 + rand.nextInt(12);
        int HP = 1 + rand.nextInt(20);
        int AC = 1 + rand.nextInt(6);

        EditText str = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.str);
        str.setText(STR);
        EditText agi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.agi);
        agi.setText(AGI);
        EditText dex = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dex);
        dex.setText(DEX);
        EditText wis = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wis);
        wis.setText(WIS);
        EditText intel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.intel);
        intel.setText(INT);
        EditText con = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.con);
        con.setText(CON);
        EditText hp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.baseHP);
        hp.setText(HP);
        EditText ac = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.baseAC);
        ac.setText(AC);
        }
    };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newchar);
    Button randomButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.randomButton);
    randomButton.setOnClickListener(randomButtonListener);
}


}
```

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearlayoutNew1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/background" >
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/newCharLabel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/new_character_screen"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:textColor="@color/splash"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameLabel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/nameLabel"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textColor="@color/splash"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/statsLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow01"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/strLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/strLabel"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="@color/splash"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/str"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="3"
            android:inputType="number" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/agiLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/agiLabel"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="@color/splash"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/agi"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="3"
            android:inputType="number"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dexLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dexLabel"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="@color/splash"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/dex"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="3"
            android:inputType="number"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow02"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/intLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/intLabel"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="@color/splash"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/intel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="3"
            android:inputType="number"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/wisLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/wisLabel"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="@color/splash"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/wis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="3"
            android:inputType="number"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/conLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/conLabel"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="@color/splash"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/con"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="3"
            android:inputType="number"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayoutNew02"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/baseHPLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hpLabel"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="@color/splash"/>
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/baseHP"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="3"
            android:inputType="number"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/baseACLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/acLabel"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="@color/splash"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/baseAC"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="3"
            android:inputType="number"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayoutNew03"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/randomButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/randomButton"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have also tried setting the onClick in xml to setup a specific onClick method.  Still the same error so I must have a problem elsewhere.  Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Class File Editor

Source not found

/ Compiled from Resources.java (version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit)
public class android.content.res.Resources {
  
  // Method descriptor #13 (Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;Landroid/util/DisplayMetrics;Landroid/content/res/Configuration;)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 4
  public Resources(android.content.res.AssetManager assets, android.util.DisplayMetrics metrics, android.content.res.Configuration config);
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  invokespecial java.lang.Object() [1]
     4  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     8  ldc <String "Stub!">
And it keeps going

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to setText as `int`,and `it must be String.`

```
 str.setText(STR+" ");
```

**or**

```
 str.setText(String.valueof(STR));
```